# Error on saving a new product with a variable price feature D7 Ubercart and UC Var Price Module

Tags: 7, ubercart

I've got a site I converted from D6 to D7 about a year ago, and there is a small store built using Ubercart, and the products have a variable price feature on them via the [UC Variable Price Module](https://drupal.org/project/uc_varprice). I'm trying to add a new product to a client's store and we're using the variable_price module. For some reason, I'm now getting this error:

> PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'sel_options'
>   doesn't have a default value: INSERT INTO {uc_varprice_products}
>   (pfid, price_default, price_minimum, price_maximum, add_to_cart_title,
>   amount_title) VALUES (:db_insert_placeholder_0,
>   :db_insert_placeholder_1, :db_insert_placeholder_2,
>   :db_insert_placeholder_3, :db_insert_placeholder_4,
>   :db_insert_placeholder_5); Array ( [:db_insert_placeholder_0] => 18
>   [:db_insert_placeholder_1] => 15 [:db_insert_placeholder_2] =>
>   [:db_insert_placeholder_3] => [:db_insert_placeholder_4] =>
>   [:db_insert_placeholder_5] => ) in drupal_write_record() (line 7166 of
>   /var/www/vhosts/mysite.org/web/content/includes/common.inc).

I don't know if it's a permissions error on the server, if it's a bug in the module, or what. in the past the module has worked fine without any trouble, and there are no updates for the var price module. Core is up to date, adn UC is 7.x-3.6.

I've looked, but I cannot find anything on this error anywhere and was hoping that someone here might be able to point me in the right direction. Am I missing something simple, or something broken?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a bugreport for  UC Variable Price Module, and should be posted in appropriate issue queue at Drupal.org instead.

Comment: Having that said, you can use phpmyadmin or similar tool to set `sel_options` default value to something. Serialized `NULL` seems solid choice for `varvhar` and `BLOB` fields, it's `N;` if you wonder. For numeric types `0` is usually a pretty solid default.

Comment: Fair enough. As in the past, I've already posted the question to the appropriate place on the Drupal site and have thus far been unable to get anyone to pay attention to it. But I thought about trying what you mention. At this point, it's about the only choice I have.